# CKEditor plugin pastfromword got html error

Tags: html, xml, eclipse, ckeditor

I try to update the CKEditor but end up in 450 Errors of the type:
`Processing instruction not closed` and `No End Tag`. But the end tag is clearly there.
They are all thrown by ie8.html or ie11.html which I did not modify.

The path from main folder is:
    `ckeditor -> tests -> plugins -> pastfromword -> generated -> _fixture

and for example ends in`

Bold -> word2007`.

I try to use the files in Eclipse and I am not sure if the problem is Eclipse because I tried to copy element for element in a new file. When I got the error in my new file and removed the line of code. The error did not disappear. I suppose the xml tag to be the error. But I am not sure.
The following line is an example for one of the bad files.

```
<P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 8pt" class=MsoNormal>
    <B style="mso-bidi-font-weight: normal">
        <FONT size=3>
            <FONT color=#000000>This text is only bolded.
                <?xml:namespace prefix = o /><o:p></o:p>
            </FONT>
        </FONT>
    </B>
</P>
```

If you need further information I will try to provide it to you.